# Where is the game item artwork in kbreakout?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde-apps

I am looking for the location of the bricks, gift, etc artwork so that if I wanted to play around with making my own private bricks etc, I could. I know how to build kbreakout, but I cannot seem to find where game items art is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakout themes are: /usr/share/kde4/apps/kbreakout/themes/
or if you have the sources : .../kbreakout/themes/

Inside of the svgz ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG ) pictures.

[image]

```
apt-cache show inkscape

Description: vector-based drawing program
 Inkscape loads and saves a subset of the SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)
 format, a standard maintained by the WWW consortium.
 .
 Inkscape user interface should be familiar from CorelDraw and similar
 drawing programs. There are rectangles, ellipses, text items, bitmap
 images and freehand curves.
 As an added bonus, both vector and bitmap objects can have alpha
 transparency and can be arbitrarily transformed.
 .
 Inkscape supports multiple opened files and multiple views per file.
 Graphics can be printed and exported to png bitmaps.
 .
 Some of the import and export features are provided using the packages
 dia, libwmf-bin, pstoedit, skencil, imagemagick, and perlmagick.
 .
 Other extensions use ruby, libxml-xql-perl, python-numpy, and python-lxml.
 You must have these packages to make full use of all extensions and effects.
 .
 If you want to use the spellchecker, you have to install aspell and the
 respective language-pack, e.g. aspell-en or aspell-de.
Homepage: http://www.inkscape.org/
```